# CORS support in jersey?

Tags: tomcat, jersey, cors

I have seen the posts that allow for CORS support...but w.e I try, I am having 0 luck with it.

Here is the function on my angular.js for CORS:

```
var config = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: "//localhost:8080/ScienceCompanionApp/service/bpms/task/5497d038-82da-4a4e-83bd-2ef01b30de1a",
        headers: {
            'BPM-CONTEXT-ID':'CONTEXT',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'

        }

    }
    $http(config).success(function(data,status,headers){  //do stuff here }
```

I have added the following to my web.xml:

```
  <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

They say that was about it...but that didnt seem to do the trick, while attempting to make CORS call:

[image]

Then i tried to manually add it to my REST API:

```
 @Path("/task/{taskId}")
    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value="Get BPMS Task", notes="You will need to JS decrypt Header param before sending")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getTask(@ApiParam(value="bpmWorklistTaskId in the BPMS url")@PathParam("taskId") final String taskId,
                        @ApiParam(value="bpmWorklistContext in the bpms url")@HeaderParam(WORKFLOW_CONTEXT_HEADER) final String contextId) {

        logger.info("REST : getTask(" + taskId + ", " + contextId + ")");
        try {
            return Response.status(200).entity(requestProcessor.getTaskDetails(taskId, contextId)).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS").header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia").build();
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            throw createWebException(e);
        }
    }

 @Path("/task/{taskId}")
    @OPTIONS
    public Response getOptions(@ApiParam(value="bpmWorklistTaskId in the BPMS url")@PathParam("taskId") final String taskId,
            @ApiParam(value="bpmWorklistContext in the bpms url")@HeaderParam(WORKFLOW_CONTEXT_HEADER) final String contextId) 
        {
            return Response.ok()
                      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
                      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With,BPM-CONTEXT-ID,accept,bpm-context-id").build();
        }
```

still no luck :(

am i missing something?

Comment: it needs cors response headers from the server, not just the client (ex ACAO,ACAM, header whitelist, etc)

Comment: and whitelist BPM-CONTEXT-ID...

Comment: hi @dandavis i have added them to the response headers...im still not even getting the response to hit my server...as you can see it has logger for info...but the browser isnt even making the call to the service. it comes with a 403 forbidden

Comment: since you're using custom http headers, you need to make sure the server responds to the OPTIONS http method, not just the GET method. this allows the real request (not shown, but will appear after OPTIONS when correct) to be approved. if you can do a plain-jane GET (like move the header to a param), you won't need the OPTIONS support.

Comment: @dandavis  i have added what you suggest (updated above) but still it does not seem to work.

using a REST client I made a OPTIONS call to the endpoint, and i see that it does successfully get hit (via breakpoints)...however the angularJS call does not even register.

Comment: What version of Jersey are you using? I've had problems with recent versions of Jersey (2.10+) correctly calling my `@OPTIONS` method. I ended up having to add the headers in a `ContainerResponseFilter` filter to get it to work properly.

Comment: @Baldy  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>1.8</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform below steps

1. Create a filter class, say
         public class CORSResponseFilter implements Filter {

   public CORSResponseFilter() {

   }

   @Override
   public void destroy() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)throws IOException, ServletException {

   String method = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod();

   ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

   if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {

   ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
         "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");

   ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
         "origin, accept,content-type,authorization");

   ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Vary", "Origin");

   ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

   return;
   }

   chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }

   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
2. make entry in web.xml

   ```
   <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>

   <filter-class>filter.CORSResponseFilter</filter-class>
   ```

   < /filter>

   < filter-mapping>

   ```
   <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>

   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   ```

   < /filter-mapping>

Hope this help you..